# Thunk Middleware: how/why does action creator have access to dispatch when it's not passed in?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware, redux-thunk

For reference, this is the origin of the below screenshots: https://github.com/gopinav/React-Redux-Tutorials/blob/master/redux-demo/asyncActions.js

Looking at the `fetchUsers` action creator function in the below screenshot, how is `dispatch` passed into this function? Not clear how the `fetchUsers` function has access to dispatch and can pass it into the anonymous return function within `fetchUsers`.

The `store` creation in the 2nd screenshot is where the `thunkMiddleware` is applied and the `fetchUsers` is dispatched.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `fetchUsers` function _doesn't_ have access to `dispatch`. The middleware has access to dispatch, and it will pass `dispatch` into your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JLRishe answered this correctly in a comment.

`fetchUsers` is a function that returns an anonymous function. The anonymous function takes the `dispatch` function as an argument. When you call `store.dispatch(fetchUsers())`, note that you're passing the *return value* of `fetchUsers` to `store.dispatch`. Redux then calls this anonymous function, passing it the `dispatch` method as an argument. The anonymous function is then invoked and can use the passed in `dispatch` function to dispatch additional actions.

Comment: just to follow up on that: in a more simple case `store.dispatch` takes an action object as an argument, while here it takes a function as an argument and then essentially passes in to that function itself (`dispatch`) as an argument of that function. Did I characterize that correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Redux checks the type of object you pass to `dispatch`. If it's a function, it calls the function, passing it the reference to `dispatch`.